# small issue with regex in sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

i have this string:

```
 data="week 50; data; data; data; data"
```

i would like to erase the week part from it by using sed,
so that i would get:  data; data; data; data
I have come up with this but apparently is not working, any idea why?
Where is the wrong rule?

code:

```
echo ${data} | sed '/%week.*%;/s/%week.*%;//'
```

Chers

Comment: What the heck are those percent signs doing in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
echo ${data} | sed 's/week[^;]*;//'
```

Output:

```
data; data; data; data
```

This matches `week` plus up-to and including the next semi-colon (`[^;]*;`) and removes it.

If you also want to remove the extraneous space, do this:

```
 echo ${data} | sed 's/week[^;]*; *//'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to remove the semi-colon-separated field containing text that starts with "week" or is it really that you just want to remove the first field? Consider:

```
$ echo "week 50; data; data; data; data" | cut -d\; -f2-
 data; data; data; data

$ echo "week 50; data; data; data; data" | sed 's/[^;]*;//'
 data; data; data; data
```